# How to use `ImageRequest.Builder.target` in the new coil version in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, crash, android-jetpack-compose, coil

### My Gradle

```
// Coil
implementation "io.coil-kt:coil-compose:1.4.0"
```

### Problem Description

Previously I used the coil together with Google's `accompanist`, but when I migrate to the new version of the coil [as the documentation suggests](https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/compose/#migrating-from-accompanist) I'm having problems with the `target` method:

```sh
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.pokedex, PID: 13502
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: request.target must be null.
        at coil.compose.ImagePainterKt.rememberImagePainter(ImagePainter.kt:94)
...
```

### Coil Implementation

When browsing the internal code of `ImagePainter` (coil class) you can see that the `target` method really needs to be null for some reason:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun rememberImagePainter(
     request: ImageRequest,
     imageLoader: ImageLoader,
     onExecute: ExecuteCallback = ExecuteCallback.Default,
): ImagePainter {
     requireSupportedData(request.data)
     require(request.target == null) { "request.target must be null." }
...
```

### My Code

Here's my component in jetpack compose (the image component is inside a column):

```kotlin
Image(
    modifier = Modifier
        .size(120.dp)
        .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally),
    painter = rememberImagePainter(
        data = entry.imageUrl,
        builder = {
            crossfade(true)
            target {
                viewModel.calcDominantColor(it) { color ->
                    dominantColor = color
                }
            }
            transformations(CircleCropTransformation())
        },
    ),
    contentDescription = entry.pokemonName
)
```

I need the target method to do internal operations on my `viewModel` based on the `drawable` it passes as a parameter. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Coil **2.0.0** both `AsyncImage` and `rememberAsyncImagePainter` have `onSuccess` callback parameter, using which you can get the drawable as follows:

```
AsyncImage(
    model = imageURL,
    contentDescription = null,
    onSuccess = { success ->
        val drawable = success.result.drawable
    }
)
```

---

Coil **1.4.0** version:

This is intended behaviour since `rememberImagePainter` sets the `target` internally.

You can track the painter state, wait for the `Success` and get the `drawable` from it. Also use it with [`LaunchedEffect`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#LaunchedEffect(kotlin.Any,kotlin.coroutines.SuspendFunction1)) to prevent re-calculations:

```
val painter = rememberImagePainter(
    data = imageUrl,
    builder = {
        ...
    },
)
(painter.state as? ImagePainter.State.Success)
    ?.let { successState ->
        LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
            val drawable = successState.result.drawable
            viewModel.calcDominantColor(drawable) { color ->
                dominantColor = color
            }
        }
    }
Image(
    painter = painter,
    contentDescription = "...",
    modifier = Modifier
        ...
)
```

Comment: Where does the Image actually update in the UI?

Answer (score 6):

I know you follow this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jrIfGAk8PyQ&list=PLQkwcJG4YTCTimTCpEL5FZgaWdIZQuB7m&index=5
by Philipp Lackner
try this code

```
AsyncImage(
            model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
                .data(entry.imageUrl)
                .crossfade(true)
                .build(),
            contentDescription = entry.pokemonName,
            onSuccess = {
                viewModel.calcDominantColor(it.result.drawable) { color ->
                    dominantColor = color
                }
            },
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(120.dp)
                .align(CenterHorizontally)
        )
```

and use this library implementation("io.coil-kt:coil-compose:2.2.2")
and to more information https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/compose/

Answer (score 0):

**I'm also facing the same issue**

***Using this implementation***

- First, implement this library into your project

> implementation("io.coil-kt:coil-compose:2.6.0") or [newer version](https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/compose/)

- then use this code -

  ```
      val imageModel = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
           .data(data = ImageUrl)
           .build()

       AsyncImage(
           model = imageModel,
           contentDescription = null,
           onSuccess = { it ->
               val drawable = it.result.drawable
           }
       )
  ```